# htaccess Redirect subdirectory and its contents

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

Here is my initial redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1\.myinitialdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub2\.myinitialdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That basically redirects the entire website, except for `sub1` and `sub2` to the new domain.

However, I've got a wordpress install at `/wordpress` and I've got the following rule in place to redirect all of the articles:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wordpress 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

But even though the articles are being redirected correctly, the main `/wordpress` directory is not being redirected correctly. It's being redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com/blog/wordpress`

I need to be able to combine the rules, but make sure that `/worpress` and any articles within that are being redirected to `https://www.mydomain.com/blog/`

Comment: What should it get redirected to? The rule that you have seems to redirect to where you're saying it's getting redirected to.

Comment: `https://www.mydomain.com/blog/` - I edited my question to include the initial rules that must be in place as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to redirect everything from within `/wordpress/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/blog/$1 [NC,L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub1|sub2)\.myinitialdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Make sure this is first rule in `/wordpress/.htaccess` file.

Comment: This is a permanent redirect. So, should I change that `302` to `301`?

Comment: Make sure it is working as per your needs first. After verification you can change it to `301`.

Comment: That second set of conditions ... that would go within the root htaccess file, correct?